# Convert a 3 poles AC/DC battery charger into a 2 poles DC power supply?

Tags: battery, ac

I have a battery charger with a positive pole, a negative pole and a common pole, see the below diagram.
[image]
The output voltage is as follows:
positive-common 5V DC
negative-common 5V DC
positive-negative 0V

The battery specs are 10V DC at 1.5 Amp h, the battery is dead and too expensive to buy a new one.
The device that uses this battery only connects to the positive and negative terminals of the battery and is rated as a 10V device.
[image]
How do I make get 10V across positive and negative directly from the charger?

Comment: Your description of the 3 outputs is contradictory or ambiguous. At minimum it is not clear what the polarities are from your description and diagram. Does the charger even match the chemistry of the battery? The battery *is* rechargeable right? What happened to the charger you are supposed to use? I would say get a correct charger. I've never seen a case where messing around with a charger worked.

Comment: I don't think you can get there from here.